# How can I use gzipped version of jQuery in my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery says it is 31KB when it is gzipped. Can anybody please help me how to use that gzipped version in my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server will gzip it so long as the client can accept gzipped.

Answer (score 2):

Use Google's CDN for maximum caching and availability! http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery